# Adding custom Pane class to JAVAFX FXML Application using Scene Editor

Tags: java, javafx, import, scenebuilder

Okay so I have a custom pane class that I want to reference from inside FXML. When I try to change the node class to BallPane, it says it doesn't exist.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BallPane extends Pane {

    public final double radius = 20;
    private double x = radius, y = radius;
    private double dx = 1, dy = 1;
    private Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius);
    private Timeline animation;

    public BallPane() {
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        getChildren().add(circle);
        animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play(); // Start animation 
    }

    public void play() {
        animation.play();
    }

    public void pause() {
        animation.pause();
    }

    public void increaseSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1);
    }

    public void decreaseSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(
                animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 0.1 : 0);
    }

    public DoubleProperty rateProperty() {
        return animation.rateProperty();
    }

    protected void moveBall() {
        // Check boundaries 
        if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
            dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction 
        }
        if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
            dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction 
        }

        // Adjust ball position 
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
    }
}
```

I have tried this nested inside my FXML

```
    <BallPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="334.0" prefWidth="462.0" />
```

and then this in my Controller

```
@FXML
BallPane bpane;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use the default package; it doesn't play nicely with FXML (and is strongly discouraged anyway). Put your class in a named package.

Comment: Yes, that's good convention. Thanks.
Yet it doesn't fix my problem?

Still getting javafx.fxml.LoadException: BallPane is not a valid type ./FXMLDocument.fxml:11

Comment: Apparently I've been using a severely outdated version of scene editor (v2) when v8 is out.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `import` in the FXML file?

Comment: No I do not, but now I do and it works. Thanks